# Orthogonality and "diagonality" in QM

Tags: quantum-mechanics

When we describe a quantum spin in terms of the basis vectors up and down, then we know that the up and down states are orthogonal to eachother. This means that they are "opposites" in the sense that if it is in the up state, we have zero probability of measuring it in the down state.

But if we have a spin in the up state, we have a 0.5 probability of measuring it in the right (or left, or in, or out) state. Then there are states with probability in between up and right.

What word do we use to denote that two states are "independent", in the sense of measuring one with probability 0.5 conditional on the other? I came up with the geometric analogy of "diagonal states".

Comment: Do you mean to say "dependent", or "interdependent" perhaps?

Comment: Position eigenstates and momentum eigenstates have a similar relation. Being in an eigenstate of one of the two gives no predictive information about a measurement in the other basis. Here the term used to describe this is conjugate variables. However, this only holds for states that are Fourier transforms of each other like position and momentum or energy and time. I do not know a name for the more general case you ask for.

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you are asking about [mutually unbiased bases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutually_unbiased_bases). If a system is prepared in one state from such a basis $b$ (e.g. eigenstate of $\sigma^z$), then a projective measurement in a different mutually unbiased basis $b'$ (e.g. the $\sigma^x$ eigenbasis) gives equal probabilities for each of the possible outcomes. As noted in the comments, this generalises the notion of complementarity between position and momentum observables (whose eigenstates satisfy $\lvert \langle x\rvert p\rangle\rvert^2 = \rm const.$) to finite-dimensional Hilbert spaces.

For qubits/half-spins with Hilbert-space dimension $d=2$, there are three mutually unbiased bases: the eigenbases of the three Pauli operators $\sigma^{x,y,z}$. Remarkably, the number $m$ of mutually unbiased bases for general $d$ is unknown, unless $d = p^n$ for some prime $p$ and integer $n$ in which case $m = d+1$. Hence, even for $d$ as small as 6, the number of mutually unbiased bases is still (to my knowledge) an open problem.

Comment: Ah, beat me to the punch.

Comment: Related: [The number of mutually-unbiased bases in dimension $d$](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391234/the-number-of-mutually-unbiased-bases-in-dimension-d).