# How many 'independent ways' can you measure a quantum 2-state system

Tags: quantum-mechanics

This question is about the role complex number have in quantum mechanics.

In a two state system, by definition you can take a measurement and will find the system to be in either of two states. Taking this measurement again yields the same result. Quantum theory states that you can take a different measurement that will find the system to be in either of two (other) states. Furthermore, there are types of measurement such that if you measure one way, then measure the other way, there will always be a 1/2 probability to find the system in either state in the second measurement. These measurements are not quite "random" in the common sense, but depend on projections of coefficients of the states.

For this question I call two measurements such that the second has 1/2 probability to find either states "independent ways" of measuring. My question is how many independent ways, with each way independent to all others, of measuring a two state system are there? For real coefficients I think the answer is 2: way 1 gives |a> or |b>; way 2 gives [not normalised] |a> + |b> or |a> - |b>? But in quantum mechanics the coefficients are complex, so does that mean there are always 4 ways and 8 states? Do quantum systems ever have different algebras other than complex numbers, and therefore different numbers of independent ways of measuring 2 state systems?

Thanks!

As the contributors to this question kindly pointed out, the standard terminology for "independent ways" is "mutually unbiased bases", as asked and answered in this question: [Orthogonality and “diagonality” in QM](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391123/orthogonality-and-diagonality-in-qm/391139#391139)

Comment: Extremely closely related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/391123/ , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/391234/

Comment: Yes very much so thank you I will add to my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a 2 state system, the distinct physical states can be put into one-to-one correspondence with the points on a sphere, called the [Bloch sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch_sphere). In the case of a spin-$\frac12$ particle the sphere has a physical interpretation: the direction on the sphere corresponds to the direction of spin polarization. I'll use notation for a spin-$\frac12$ particle for this reason but the answer holds for any 2 state system, not only ones that come from an $SO(3)$ rotational symmetry.

Suppose you first measure the state of the particle in the $|\pm z \rangle$ basis. We want to know what measurements can be done after this so that each outcome is equally probable. As is well-known, measuring in the $|\pm x \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} (|+z\rangle \pm |-z\rangle)$ basis afterwards satisfies this. But, of course, $|\pm y \rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt 2} (|+z\rangle \pm  i |-z\rangle)$ works just as well. In fact for any direction $\hat n$ which makes a $\frac \pi 2$ angle with the $z$ axis in Euclidean space (i.e. is in the $xy$ plane), the corresponding measurement has probability $\frac12$ for each outcome. All of these are related by rotational symmetry about the $z$-axis. The general form for the basis vectors can be taken as $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2} (|+z\rangle \pm e^{i \phi} |-z\rangle)$ where $\phi$ denotes the angle that $\hat n$ makes with the $x$ axis in the $xy$ plane.

So the answer is, there are infinitely many different measurements you can do which are independent to a single one. However, you seem to be asking a stronger question; that is, what is the most number of measurements I can do so that if I pick *any two*, the second measurement always gives probability $\frac12$ for each possibility. Note that I am not requiring the first measurement to remain fixed here. Mathematically this question is what the maximum number of [mutually unbiased bases](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutually_unbiased_bases) is for a 2-dimensional Hilbert space. The answer for a two-state system is $3$, and they can be taken as $\{|\pm x \rangle \},\{ |\pm y\rangle \},\{ |\pm z\rangle \}$. Any other choice is unitarilly equivalent to this one. It is notable that, while the question is not too hard to solve for a $2$-state system, if you were to ask about larger systems, the maximum number of mutually unbiased bases is only known when the dimension of the system $d$ is a power of a prime number (in which case it is $d+1$) and is unsolved otherwise.

Comment: This is probably one of the best answers I have seen on an overflow site, or perhaps even in general. Understood my question exactly, gave a direct answer, placed it into an easy to understand theoretical explanation, provided the correct terminology for my question, and gave some more advanced (and interesting) context. Thank you!

Comment: Only thing I'm still curious about is whether other algebras and hence spheres of different dimension apply. I guess since it was omitted in your answer they don't. So I guess when spins and the groups on which particle fields are based are discussed, that is a different thing.

Comment: For a $d$ state system, the physical states are not described as points on a sphere, but as points in a [complex projective space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_projective_space) $\mathbb C P^{d-1}$. You could describe them as points on a $2d-1$-sphere but this description is redundant. It just so happens that $\mathbb CP^1$ is a sphere, specifically the [Riemann sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere). The probability corresponds to a particular distance measure called the [Fubini-Study metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini–Study_metric)...

Comment: The question you ask doesn't really have anything to do with groups, spin, etc, just the dimension of the Hilbert space. The reason is that a measurement just corresponds to a choice of an orthonormal basis in the Hilbert space. Group representations tell you that the Hilbert space should have certain operators acting on it which describe the symmetries, but nothing here depends on what operators are present on the Hilbert space. The symmetry could place constraints on the dimension of the Hilbert space under certain assumptions but that is not closely related to the question at hand.

Comment: thanks for your comment. I am not so much interested in Hilbert spaces with different dimensions (for simplicity I am only considering 2 state spaces), but rather a Hilbert space over a different (not complex) field (which I have called an "algebra" because I don't want to restrict things prematurely). So as far as I understand that would be a system of measurements each having only two possible results, but with more than 3 mutually unbiased bases as described in the answer. It's probably a moot point though if, as it sounds, this is not physically expressed. @Logan M

Comment: You can ask a similar question for finite-dimensional modules over any normed division algebra, and perhaps in more generality if you decide how to generalize things. I don't know of any research on this though I have not looked for it. I don't think there will be any direct application to physics though, while mutually unbiased bases for complex Hilbert spaces do have quite a bit of use in quantum information theory.