# Can QM be used to model 2 state systems with more than 4 linearly independent observables?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin, measurements, linear-algebra, observables

Suppose I have a system (e.g., a particle) and I have different physical measurement apparatus which can act on it. Each of the measurement apparatus (observables) has 2 distinct labeled outcomes, thus in QM I can represent them by 2-dimensional self-adjoint operators or alternatively 2x2 Hermitian matrices. I know these observables act on the same Hilbert space since I can experimentally determine that these 4 observables don't commute.

I can experimentally determine if the observables are mutually linearly independent by taking expectation values, e.g., I can check to see if $S_X$ observable is linearly independent from $S_Y$ and $S_Z$, by checking to see if $\langle x_+$|$S_X$|$x_+\rangle$ can be made from linear combination of $\langle x_+$|$S_Y$|$x_+\rangle$ and $\langle x_+$|$S_Z$|$x_+\rangle$ and same for $\langle x_-$|$S_X$|$x_-\rangle$.

From linear algebra we know, $2\times2$ complex hermitian matrix has 4 free parameters. If we remove the global phase parameter (i.e., $S_I$), there are only 3 free parameters left, hence for convenience we usually represent the observables using a basis consisting of the 3 Pauli operators and Identity, i.e., $S_X$, $S_Y$, $S_Z$ and $S_I$. My question is what happens if I experimentally determine a set of more than 4 linearly independent non-commuting observables, it appears from my perspective regular QM cannot model such circumstance.

I want to know where did my logic go wrong or why such scenarios cannot physically occur? If such scenarios could theoretically occur, how can we go about modeling them? I stumbled upon this question because I didn't understand why 2 level systems have the structure of $\text{SU}(2)$ / $\text{SO}(3)$ or why the canonical quantum observables have the algebra they do. I know it is physically true and makes sense since spin can be added with regular angular momentum, but physically why can't 2 level quantum systems have say 5 or more "mutually unbiased bases", is it just restrictions based on the mathematics behind our theories?

There might be a lot of math I might be missing, I am lost on this topic and I would greatly appreciate pointers on what/where to look for relevant materials.

Edit: [This comment has a similar idea to mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/394352/how-many-independent-ways-can-you-measure-a-quantum-2-state-system#comment884373_394354)

Comment: There is no problem in finding $4$ linearly independent observables on $C^2$: $I, \sigma_1,\sigma_2,\sigma_3$. If you find more than $4$ (real) linearly independent observables it just means that your Hilbert space cannot have dimension $2$ because the real vector space of Hermitian operators in a two-dimensional (complex) Hilbert space has dimension $4$.

Comment: Thank you for your quick comment @valter-moretti, I really love your detailed answers on Physics StackExchange. Isn't the dimension of the Hilbert space given by the spectrum of the Observables? How can I reconcile that fact with my experimentally determined set of 4 linearly independent observables? Also isn't **_I_** not an observable, so normally we only have a set of 3 linearly independent observables?

Comment: $I$ **is** an observable, why not? The dimension of the Hilbert space is not the spectrum of the observables. I do not understand why you think it...

Comment: Think of the observable $\hat{S}^2= \sum_{k=1}^3 \hat{S}_k^2$ in the spin Hilbert space. It is proportional to $I$. For the same reason you see that the number of elements of the spectrum of a generic  operator is not the dimension of the Hilbert space. I agree that, in **finite dimension** Hilbert spaces,  the **maximal number** of elements of the spectrum of the possible observables is the dimension of the Hilbert space.

Comment: @MichaelChen Maybe you're not taking into account that eigenstates can be *degenerate*. Take a spin 1/2 particle which can be in either of two sites (1 and 2). The states (1,up) and (2,up) are independent states but they're both eigenstates of s_z with eigenvalue 1/2.

Comment: I think you're right that **_I_** can be an observable, so for the sake of argument let's consider the case with a set of more than 4 linearly independent observables. I thought we derive the Hilbert space from the observables, so I assumed the "dimension" (i.e., # of points) of the spectrum must equal the dimension of the Hilbert space in finite dimensions. Are you suggesting from my given experimental results I should model the system in a 4-dimensional space, which contains different 2D subspaces spanned by the observables?

Comment: @ValterMoretti to keep it simple, let's just assume a point spectrum with a finite number of elements. Are you implying the maximal number of elements of the spectrum of the possible observables is not the maximal # of labels I have on each measurement apparatus?

Comment: @fra_pero I think degeneracy may play a part but I don't see how. Suppose I have the Pauli spin operators and a site projection measurement modelled by **1** 1><1 + **2** 2><2. I can experimentally determine this operator commutes with spin operators so I can place it in a different Hilbert space. My scenario hits a problem for more than 4 linearly independent non-commuting observables.

Comment: I see you're right, I've mistaken your question. So I think that it really boils down to @ValterMoretti first comment.

Comment: @MichaelChen The elements of the spectrum are exactly the outcomes of experiments of that observable, so the maximal number of label is always equal to the complex dimension of the Hilber space. If the dimension is $2$ every observable may have one or two labels. I don not think I am understanding the issue you are discussing....

Comment: @ValterMoretti From your comments, it seems that you are suggesting if I experimentally determine a set of 5 or more linearly independent non-commuting 2 point spectrum observables, I should model such systems using a Hilbert space of more than 2 dimensions. I think this might be possible but the mathematical model might be underdetermined from an experimental view. Your answer should solve my issue by disproving/refuting the premise of the 2 state system in my question. I previously thought the # of labels as the dimension of the Hilbert space is sufficient to characterize the system.

Comment: " thus in QM I can represent them by 2-dimensional self-adjoint operators or alternatively 2x2 Hermitian matrices" This is not a consequence of your premise: "Suppose you have a system (e.g., a particle) and I have different physical measurement apparatus which can act on it. Each of the measurement apparatus (observables) has 2 distinct labeled outcomes". Consider a spinless particle in $L^2(R)$ and next the partity observables referred to **three** different **origins**: $(P_i \psi)(x):= \psi(x_i-x)$, $i=1,2,3$. These three observable are linearly independent, each of them has two outcomes.

Comment: ...but $\dim(L^2(R))= \infty$ and every  $P_i$ is an "$\infty$-dimensional matrix" for every choice of the Hilbert basis.